# Elastic search query to filter array by two conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an Elastic Search query to modify the data received but I don't have much knowledge about Elastic and I don't know how to accomplish that.

I have an array of "tasks" and I need to receive those tasks filtered by some conditions. Right now the query is filtering by:
- Must be assigned or created for specific "group"
- Should be asigned or created for specific "user"

The group and the user are determined by the user that make the request.

```
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "taskId",
            "tenantId-createdAt-circuitId",
            "assignedToGroup",
            "assignedToUser",
            "assignedToRole",
            "circuitId",
            "createdAt",
            "createdByRole",
            "currentStatus",
            "taskType",
            "tenantId",
            "history",
            "payload",
            "slaExpiresAt",
            "taskDefinitionName",
            "taskDefinitionId",
            "input"
        ]
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "createdAt": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "tenantId.keyword": "tenant1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "createdAt": {
                                    "gte": "now-1y/d",
                                    "lte": "now+1d/d"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "createdByGroup.keyword": "SUPERVISORES"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "assignedToGroup": "SUPERVISORES"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "assignedToUser.keyword": "supervisorsucursal1@btekstudio1.onmicrosoft.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "createdByUser.keyword": "supervisorsucursal1@btekstudio1.onmicrosoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to start handling a "role" condition, so the final query needs to receive:
- Tasks asigned or created for the user's group (and also needs to receive tasks on that group that doesn't have any role assigned)
- Tasks assigned to the user's role
- Tasks assigned o created for the user

This is my mapping https://pastebin.com/yE6PGLDQ
And this is a sample task https://pastebin.com/p0942qfv

Comment: Add your mapping and sample data

Comment: Sure! added both